# Deduplicate: different file contents sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a multi-project built with sbt, and I would like to build an executable jar using sbt-assembly plugin. However, I get an error while building the jar file:

```
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:org/slf4j/helpers/Util.class
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/jars/neo4j-spark-connector-2.1.0-M4.jar:org/slf4j/helpers/Util.class
```

What should I add to the merge strategies in order to fix this error?
I defined merge strategy for org.neo4j and org.slf4j, but it does not seem to work.

build.sbt file:

```
lazy val overrides = Seq("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.5")

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven",
  dependencyOverrides ++= overrides
)

lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "neo4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "typesafe", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("net", "jpountz", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
    case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
  }
)

lazy val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.1.0-M4",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.neo4j.driver" % "neo4j-java-driver" % "1.5.1",
  "com.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "4.1",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.5",
  "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "6.2.4"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "DemoTest"
  )
  .aggregate(core, consumer, producer)


lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )

lazy val consumer = (project in file("consumer"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  ).settings(
    mainClass in assembly := Some("consumer.SparkConsumer"),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_consumer.jar"
  ).dependsOn(core)

lazy val producer = (project in file("producer"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  ).settings(
  mainClass in assembly := Some("producer.KafkaCheckinsProducer"),
  assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_producer.jar"
).dependsOn(core)
```